# Help to set up Zend navigation based on own file structure

Tags: zend-navigation

I am quite new to ZF, and I have got to follow a company file structure and set up Zend Navigation upon it.

I have got a included script like this:

```
<?php
//test1.php
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml( $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.$sitePath.'lib/navigation.xml', 'nav');
$container = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->navigation($container);
$view->addScriptPath($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.$sitePath);
echo $view->render('test1.php');
?>

<!--And in my View Script:-->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        You are in: <?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Content of your page here.
    </div>
</body>
```

However I have this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getParams() on a non-object in C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\1.10\library\Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc.php on line 133

Could anyone point me out where I go wrong? A lot of samples are using bootstrap and MVC but in my project I have to stick with the old file structure (Non-MVC), and I am struggling now.

I am studying these examples:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your lib/navigation.xml file? Could you show it?